# Android Change AlertDialog.builder. to equivalent imageview

Tags: android

How can i get the equivalent in terms of imageview.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setTitle("List of Exhibitors");


int selected = -1; // does not select anything

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, selected,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Select " + exIdList[which],
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent i = new Intent(mContext,
                        ExhibitorDetailsActivity.class);
                Exhibitors exhibitor = webItemsHelper.getExhibitorById(Long.parseLong(exIdList[which].toString()));
                i.putExtra("exhId", exhibitor.getNid());
                i.putExtra("exhName", exhibitor.getName());
                i.putExtra("exhStand", exhibitor.getStand());
                i.putExtra("exhSectors", exhibitor.getSector());
                i.putExtra("exhDesc", exhibitor.getDescription());
                i.putExtra("exhFav", exhibitor.getFavoris());


                mContext.startActivity(i);

            }
        });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: _How can i get the equivalent in terms of imageview._ can u specify exact thing plz?

Comment: instead of displaying an alertdialog i want an imageview but which displays the selected information at index which

Comment: so you have to create custom dialog for that

Comment: yes but when i click on the region i want a pin to appear then when i click on the pin the alert dialog appear with the data but the pin must be in the region selected